# How do I create a delay between SendKeys.Send C#

Tags: c#

Obviously this doesn't work correctly. I want to use C# and not AutoIt. What could make this work better?

```
{
     Process.Start("iexplore.exe");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     SendKeys.Send("{F6}" + "http://google.com/" + "{Enter}");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

     int counter = 1;
     while ( counter <= 10 )
     SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}" + "{SUBTRACT}");
     counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? can you explore your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SendWait()` insted of `Send()`. That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something here but if it is C# and if you have the following statement :-

```
while(count <=10)
SendKeys.Send (....)
```

wouldn't that be an infinite loop since the increment statement for counter is not present within the block of the while loop?

For the delay, try using the following :-

```
while(counter <= 10)
{
   SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}" + "{SUBTRACT}");
   counter = counter + 1;
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

The above answer is assuming that you want the current thread to block and that there is no other processing being done in the while loop